# Loop AJAX Request Every 5 Seconds

Tags: jquery, ajax, setinterval

I have code that uploads files from web page to a server at our office which then processes and updates a MySQL database on the website with the result.

The first request posts job information to a .php file that takes care of the uploading. The second request then uses another .php to check the MySQL database to see if the job record has been processed (job_processed=1). This should loop every 5 seconds.

As best I can tell, the second request only fires once. If the files are uploaded and processed quickly enough, the below code works. However if I upload lots of files, the second request doesn't loop and returns with empty results. I'm not sure why the html is updated with empty results if the processing has not finished in time as job_processed has to equal 1 for the results div html to be updated.

```
 $('#continue').click(function(){
   $('#loading-container').show();
    // Upload Files
    var ajaxurl = '/upload.php',
    data =  {'upload_dir': $('input:hidden[name=upload_dir]').val()};
    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {   
      // Loop
      var obj = JSON.parse(response);
      var tid = setInterval(checkresult, 5000);
      function checkresult() {
        // Check Result
        ajaxurl = 'check-result.php',
        data =  {'job_id': obj.job_id};
        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {                 
          obj = JSON.parse(response);      
          if (obj.job_processed == "1") {
            $('#loading-container').hide();
            $('#continue').after('<div id="results"><p><br>A: ' + obj.a_records 
              + '<br>B: ' + obj.b_records
              + '<br>C: ' + obj.c_records 
              + '<br></p></div>');
            abortTimer();
          }
        });
      }
      function abortTimer() {
        clearInterval(tid);
      }
    });
 });
```

I'm fairly new to JQuery and web programming in general so any help much appreciated.

Comment: You should really use the observer pattern for this. AJAX polling is a bad solution which does not scale.

Comment: Thanks Rory, I'll look into observer pattern. However, this is only for our remote staff to use once a week. That will mean it will be used 4 times per week so unless our workforce expanded dramatically, I can't see too many problems with traffic etc. With that in mind, do you have any thoughts regarding getting the above code working?

Comment: It turns out that the code above is fine. When the job record is being created in MySQL the job_processed value is being set to 1 instead of 0 by default. Therefore if the processing is done before the first setinterval, the result is already present in MySQL and so the correct result is displayed. If the processing is still ongoing after setinterval then the empty result is displayed due to job_processed being set to 1 even though processing hasn't finished.

Comment: I can't figure out why job_processed is defaulting to 1 even though in phpmyadmin it is set to default value of 0 so I'll start a new question for that as the code above is not the cause of the empty result.